# Making all Linux network interface (bridged) in a qemu VM use dhcp

Tags: virtualization, linux-networking, dhcp, qemu

I have a small application which takes in kernel code, and spins up VMs. I've been using this for kernel development. It is helpful and very fast when I want to spin up VMs with different kernel codes.
The application uses qemu, and generates the qemu command on the fly based on the given options.
The problem I am facing is ever changing network interface names.

The initial setup was such, that the interface names were `ens*`, and I had the following configuration in the `/etc/network/interfaces` to configure them to dhcp

```
allow-hotplug ens3
iface ens3 inet dhcp
```

I had a number of them, to make sure if the names gets pushed from `ens3` to `ens7` (maybe due to added qcow as scsi devices), the network interface `ens7` still gets configured.
It was working fine.

Now with the new Linux kernel 6.4-rc, I observe that the names of the interfaces are coming up as enp0s*. Now my `/etc/network/interfaces` configuration is not working.
I can't keep changing the `/etc/network/interfaces` file according to kernel, cause that defeats the purpose of simply changing kernel code path and spinning up VMs. Btw, this was working fine for 2 years, and for kernel ranging from 4.19 to 6.1 (havent tested 6.2 and 6.3)

My question is,
is there a default way to configure the network, such that any and all network interfaces come up with dhcp.
Basically, something like

```
allow-hotplug all
iface all inet dhcp
```

Answer (score 2):

There's several ways of doing this.

You could

- generate /etc/network/interfaces during the boot process, using the names assigned
- disable the renaming of devices (initially assigned eth0, eth1 ... will still be available by speciftying `net.ifnames=0` on the kernel command line
- Use udev rules to assign a name based on the MAC address

Comment: The second one changes it to older `eth` format. I like the first one. Can you point out how to do this? Maybe yourself, or a link which describes this clearly.

Comment: You'll find a list of the devices in /sys/class/net - just exclude 'lo' and mailemerge your config.